# Security on Spring resources only works with '@PreAuthorize'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I try to secure some REST resources using a `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` it doesn't work. I can only accomplish my goal using `@PreAuthorize` or setting the security on the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Actually, the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is stealing all possibilities on `HttpSecurity` settings. I believe that it have something to do with filtering order. I searched for information on the documentation but found it quite vague. I know that on the **Spring Boot version 1.5+ the filtering order of `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`** has been changed, and I only managed to get it to work after setting a new order on the properties: `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3`

Being more specific, this code (on `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`) doesn't have any result:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatcher(new OAuthRequestedMatcher())
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/hello").access("hasAnyRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/api/me").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

It is only possible to protect `"/api/hello"` and `"/api/me"` annotating `@PreAuthorize` on the controller methods:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')")
@GetMapping("/api/hello")
public ResponseEntity<?> hello() {
    String name = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
    String msg = String.format("Hello %s", name);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(msg, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

It is working, however, I fear that it could be done in a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I found the solution. The problem is indeed related to the filtering order. The guys at Pivotal changed the **Oauth2 Resource Filter Order**, as you can see in this passage taken from **Spring Boot 1.5 release note**:

> OAuth 2 Resource Filter
>
> The default order of the OAuth2 resource filter has changed from 3 to
>   SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER - 1. This places it after the
>   actuator endpoints but before the basic authentication filter chain.
>   The default can be restored by setting
>   security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3

However, as pointed by @ilovkatie on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822875/springboot-1-5-x-security-oauth2/42823392#42823392), the order of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was also changed to 100, taken precedence over `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`.

So, **instead of changing `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`'s order on properties, a more elegant solution would be to use `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` on `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.**

This will make the resources configuration take precedence over `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and it will be possible to set security using `HttpSecurity` on the `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`, making unnecessary to use `@PreAuthorize` annotation.