# Feign Exception 403 after updating to Spring Boot 1.5.8 and Finchley/Edgware Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, microservices, feign

I'm relatively new to microservices and I've been trying to use this [proof-of-concept application](https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics) that uses `Spring Boot` and `Spring Cloud`.

The problem is that, while the app runs fine on `Spring Boot 1.3.5` and `Spring Cloud Brixton.RELEASE`, it breaks when upgrading either one of them.

The error occurs when registering a new account, and it gives the following error:

```
status 403 reading AuthServiceClient#createUser(User); content:↵{"timestamp":1510753211255,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/uaa/users"}
```

And the stack trace:

```
2017-11-15 15:40:11.284 ERROR 9072 --- [nio-6000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/accounts] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException: status 403 reading AuthServiceClient#createUser(User); content: {"timestamp":1510753211255,"status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Access Denied","path":"/uaa/users"}] with root cause
```

As this seems to be a Feign error, and `AuthServiceClient.java` seems to be the culprit, I've included it here:

```
@FeignClient(name = "auth-service")
public interface AuthServiceClient {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/uaa/users", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
void createUser(User user);

}
```

As there have been no changes to the code whatsoever, I don't understand what the cause could be and what to do to fix this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there was this magic property that made it work again:

```
security.oauth2.resource.filter-order: 3
```

in `auth-service.properties`

Further reading here:
[SpringBoot 1.5.x + Security + OAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822875/springboot-1-5-x-security-oauth2)